# Странное кеширование uwsgi + nginx. Как выключить?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Так сложилось, что пришлось пилить на vps проект на django. Nginx + uwsgi + django настроил, всё проверил, работает. Но вот проблема. При запуске uwsgi крутится всё в кеше. То бишь, когда меня какой-то файл, любой текст. Речь о .py файлах. Изменения вступают в силу только после перезапуска uwsgi. Подскажите, как выключить это кеширование на время разработки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не кэширование, просто runserver стандартный автоматически перезагружается при изменениях в файлах (в DEBUG режиме).

При разработке используйте runserver встроенный в Django или можно [настроить uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#py-auto-reload) для автоматической перезагрузки.

Comment: с английским беда, помогите с настройкой)

Comment: просто при запуске uwsgi указывайте флаг:
`--py-autoreload 1`

Comment: и он будет перегружаться раз в секунду?

Comment: при изменениях в коде