# кэш конфигурации django

Tags: python, django, settings, uwsgi

Сайт работает по такой связке:

```
nginx <-> socket <-> uwsgi <-> Django
```

в файле settings.py были прописаны неверные данные для подключения к БД. Я их заменил на верные, но ошибка в логе та же - пытается подключиться по старым данным:

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user_old'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Как сбросить "кэш настроек"

Comment: Перезапустить тот процесс uwsgi, который отвечает за этот экземпляр Django.

Comment: @Sergey, да спасибо. Не могу найти каким образом его перезапустить, пока по  новой запускаю uwsgi --ini file.ini. Как убить старый процесс?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Странное кеширование uwsgi + nginx. Как выключить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/415647/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-uwsgi-nginx-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в конфигурации вашего uwsgi-приложения [параметр](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload)

```
touch-reload = /path/to/django/project/folder/restart.txt
```

Создайте в корне каталога django-проекта файл restart.txt

```
$ touch /path/to/django/project/folder/restart.txt
```

И перезапустите uwsgi. После этого выполнение команды `touch` на этом файле или любые изменения в нём будут приводить к [мягкому перезапуску uwsgi-приложения](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html).